# Warning: odbc_fetch_array(): 12 is not a valid ODBC result resource 1

Tags: php

I'm trying to call a function php to another class, but when run the loop... coming a problem. The function have a param and I need run a "while" to take a idUser that I have in the DataBase.
Here's the code

```
<?php
class Roles {
public function __construct() {
    Roles::class;
}
public function rolName($param) {

    $query = "select NombreRol
            from USUARIOS";
            join Roles
            on Roles.idRol = Usuarios.idRol
            where Usuarios.idUser = $param";
    $cur = odbc_do($connection, $query);
    while($row=odbc_fetch_row($cur)){ 
        echo $nameR = odbc_result($cur, 1);
    }
    odbc_close($connection);
}
```

*** the other class ***

```
<?php
include 'Roles.php';
class claseUsuarios extends Roles{
function listUs(){
    $roles = new Roles();

    $query = "SELECT * FROM USUARIOS";
    $cur = odbc_do($connection, $query);
    if ($cur){
    while($row=odbc_fetch_array($cur)){                
              echo $row['idUser']; 
              echo $row['Name']; 
              echo $row['Identifi']; 
              echo $row['lastName']; 
              echo $row['lastName2']; 
              echo $row['Phone']; 
              echo $row['Celphone']; 
              $roles->rolName($row['idUser']); 
              $date = odbc_result($cur, 10); echo $date; 
          }
    odbc_close($connection);
    }
}
```

}

And this's the problem:

***Warning: odbc_fetch_array(): 12 is not a valid ODBC result resource in C:\wamp64\www\Analisis\controller\claseUsuarios.php on line***

Thanks for help me

Comment: You have a typo in your first SQL statement